# send a ping to multiple ip addresses at the same time

Tags: java, ping, xml, text

i did a code wish send a ping to multiple ip adresses and get the value of time from each ping request and then print write the result in a from of a matrix in a text file....anyway my problem is that after i finished my code i figure out that i should send the ping to these adresses at the same time or in my code i did send it consecutively to the adresses.i really i hope if someone helps me with it...
code:

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.FlowLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Formatter;
   import java.util.List;

   import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
   import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
   import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

  import org.w3c.dom.Document;
  import org.w3c.dom.Element;
   import org.w3c.dom.Node;
  import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


 public class Pinggg extends JFrame{
    private boolean stop = false;  // start or stop the ping



public Pinggg(){
   Container cp = this.getContentPane();
   cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));

   JButton btnStart=new JButton("demarrer le test");   
   cp.add(btnStart);
   btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        stop = false;
        try {
            final Formatter x = new Formatter("C:/Users/VAIO/workspace/tcc/gastoon/kkk.txt");
            PrintWriter writer;
            writer = new PrintWriter("C:Users/VAIO/workspace/tcc/gastoon/kkk.txt");

             for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++) {
                 if (stop) break;
                     // check if STOP button has been pushed,

                                    //  which changes the stop flag to true



               DocumentBuilderFactory BuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 


                 DocumentBuilder db=BuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                 Document doc=db.parse("C:/Users/VAIO/workspace/tcc/gastoon/adresStore.xml");
                 doc.normalize();


                 NodeList rootNodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("connection");
                 Node rootNode=rootNodes.item(0);
                 Element rootElement=(Element) rootNode;

                 NodeList l=rootElement.getElementsByTagName("users");
                 Node users=l.item(0);
                 Element element=(Element) users;

                 NodeList nl=element.getElementsByTagName("user");
                 List<String> allIps = new ArrayList<String>();

                  for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){

                   Node user=nl.item(i);
                   Element ele=(Element) user;
                   String adrss=ele.getElementsByTagName("ipAdress").item(0).getTextContent();//+" -n 1";
                   //System.out.println(adrss);
                   allIps.add(i, adrss);
                   //writer.print(allIps.get(i)+" ");
                   //  System.out.println(adrss);
                   //System.out.println(i);

                   //   writer.format("%s  ",i);
                   //writer.println( adrss);
                  }


                //  for(String n : allIps)

               //{
                //    writer.print(allIps+" ");   
               //}
                  writer.println("\n");






                    for(int j=0;j<allIps.size();j++)
                     {
                        //writer.print(allIps.get(i)+" ");


                         String pingCmd = "ping " +allIps.get(j) +" -n 1";
                         String pingResult = "";
                         String str="";

                          try {
                           Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                           Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

                           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                           String inputLine;
                             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                                    {

                               // writer.println(inputLine);

                                //System.out.println(inputLine);
                                  pingResult += inputLine;
                                    }

                                 String[] lines = pingResult.split("\n");
                                 List<String> bb = new ArrayList<String>();

                                    for (int k=0;k<lines.length;k++) {



                                     String line=lines[k];

                                      if ((line.contains("temps=") && (line.contains(allIps.get(j))))){
                                       // Find the index of "time="
                                       int index = line.indexOf("temps=");
                                       String time = line.substring(index + "temps=".length(),line.indexOf("ms"));
                                       //bb.add(time);
                                     //  writer.print(allIps.get(j)+" ");
                                       writer.print(time);

                                       //System.out.println(allIps.get(j)+" ");

                                       System.out.println(time);
                                         }
                                      else {
                                          writer.print("NON"+" ");
                                      }

                                       }
                                      int[]tab=new int[allIps.size()];
                                        for(int d=0;d<tab.length;d++ ){

                                    }


                                    }





                         catch (IOException ie) {
                            System.out.println(ie);
                         }


                }}

          writer.flush(); 
             }//}


  catch (SAXException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
   catch (IOException e1)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

    catch (ParserConfigurationException e1)
  {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
  } 


              }    

        }



   );






      JButton btnStop = new JButton("Analyser le test ");
      cp.add(btnStop);
      btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            stop = false;  // set the stop flag
         }
      }); 






      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      cp.setBackground(Color.black);
      setTitle("PING");
      setSize(300, 120);
      setVisible(true);

      }     

       }
```

Comment: @yoonix, vote to migrate the question and we'll get it shifted over.

Comment: That formatting is horrible...

Comment: What is your question? This is just a 200+ line code dump.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "i should send the ping to these adresses [sic] at the same time".

1) Create a threadppol and send your requests through that. This will batch up your ping requests (to the size of the threadpool). However this is technically not "at the same time".

2) Ping the broadcast address. Whether or not this works (or rather works how you think it works) depends on your network setup. It won't work on the Internet, but it may work on a corporate LAN. So it depends on the nature of the IP addresses you are trying to ping.